# how to check if TextBox1 contain more then one character

Tags: vba

the TextBox1 should contain numbers ( like 88.7  or 21.5    .etc )

i want make sure that the sub will stop if the character ( . )  duplicated by mistake like this ( 88..7 ) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would filter user input as they type:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
   'allow numbers, periods, and backspace
   If Not (KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57) And Not KeyAscii = 46 And Not KeyAscii = 8 Then KeyAscii = 0
   
   'but only a single period
   If KeyAscii = 46 And InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ".") > 0 Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub
```